# Capturing data entered into Google Sheets and sending it through HTTP?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My goal is fairly simple but I have been struggling with this issue for days now, maybe someone could help with my problem

I am working with a CRM which is used to organize my customer's information, this CRM allows me to upload new contacts by sending an http post request with the clients information values.
But since I am fairly new to coding I am struggling with the retrieval of values entered into Google Sheets and sending them using this HTTP url. I am trying to do capture the data as soon as it is entered.

One more important note is that the values entered into Google Sheets is sent there using a script ( I am not sure what kind, it is sent by another user in the spreadsheet and he runs some sort of automatic integration ) so the edits are not done manually.
I managed to install the onChange trigger which indeed captures entries sent by the script, I tried to use the following to capture the rows:

```
function onChange(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var values = row.getValue();

  Logger.log(values);    
 }
```

But I am receiving this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRow' of undefined
    at onChange(Webhook:4:21)
```

I tried using getValues() too but it gives out the same error

How can I get and capture the whole row that was entered when the trigger was fired?
And how is it possible to then send this data using an HTTP post request?

Answer (score 0):

### Use onEdit instead

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#application_triggers) `An installable edit trigger runs when a user modifies a value in a spreadsheet` whereas `An installable change trigger runs when a user modifies the structure of a spreadsheet itself` which means a modification in the Spreadsheet, for instance adding a new sheet.

As you can see in the [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) `onChange` event doesn't have a `range` attribute that's why you get `undefined`.

I'd use the following code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var values = row.getValue();

  Logger.log(values);
}
```

### You can make HTTP requests by using the UrlFetchApp

Like mentioned in the [documentation example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params):

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.google.com/');
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

### References

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)